# Testing for actual presence of image in image tag with rspec-capybara on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara-webkit

In the emails I send out, I include a picture, and I want to make sure that it actually loaded one. So, in the style of an Mailer View Spec, I would like a Capybara RSpec Matcher, that tells me if this image has actually been rendered as an image (or if just has the alt-tag because it didn't fidn it)
Do you know if there is some option?

Comment: I'm not sure there's any way to do this.  What's done with the image is up to the browser.  You might be able to check the MIME type that the server is providing, but modern browsers don't really care about MIME types of images anyway.  I think it's sufficient to check that the `img` tag's `src` attribute matches what you expect.  You can then visit that image URL and check that the MIME type is correct, or even check the actual image data.  If that's all correct, it's pretty safe to assume that the browser will do what you want.

Comment: @Jim I had the problem that if a user didnt have a picture then the fall-back-standard image has not been put inside the email.. So I wanted a test whithout checking if it's normal or fallback picture

Comment: Actually maybe I should just do it by checking for errors when opening the path specified in img src

Comment: Yeah, I'd check that the `src` attribute is what you expect, and if you want additional confirmation, test that the URL in `src` is accessible.